# Call function in another controller from a controller in Yii

Tags: controller, yii

I want to call a function in another controller from the controller.

```
class FirstController extends Controller {
      public function test1() { return 'OK'; }
}
class SecondController extends Controller {
      public function callTest1() { First::test1(); }
}
```

--> server error
Help me resolve it.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot call that method directly because it's not `static`, so you 'd have to create an instance of `FirstController` first. When you want to do that, use [`CWebApplication::createController`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#createController-detail):

```
// supply appropriate route in place of 'first/index'
list($first) = Yii::app()->createController('first/index');
$first->test1();
```

However, there shouldn't be a need to call methods from another controller; this is a bad code smell. Perhaps it would be more appropriate to refactor your code and pull it out of the controller (maybe into a model).

Comment: I do it, but it still error. If we need to handle something which are decleared in a function of another controller, what should we do to handle it [ in current controller ], without call function of another controller. Could u show me what better to do, to change my rigid mind. thank u so much

Comment: @HuyTran, You may add in components/controller.php method witch will call from second/index and first/index

Answer (score 1):

The word 'Controller' should not be used when calling createController() and you should take [0] element of the result, before calling functions

```
 $process = Yii::app()->createController('First'); //create instance of FirstController
 $process=$process[0];
 $process->test1(); //call function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Yii::$app->runAction()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 basic application following component will be use to call action

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controllername/create', $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using createController which creates an instance based on a route, when calling via code, it's probably best to use createControllerByID.

```
    $first = Yii::$app->createControllerByID('first');
    $first->test1();
```

Make sure test1 is public function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call directly your function: first create instance of controller, then call function:

```
$process = Yii::app()->createController('FirstController'); //create instance of controller

$process->test1(); //call function
```

Answer (score 0):

If method `test1` in your `FirstController` is not using `$this` you can simply make it `static`. Instead of:

```
public function test1() { return 'OK'; }
```

sign it as:

```
public static function test1() { return 'OK'; }
```

Then you can call it from everywhere:

```
FirstController::test1();
```

It all depends on your needs...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

for PatientsController and method printPublicReport() with $params = $patientId, $appId, $testIds

```
    list($patient) = Yii::$app->createController('patients/print-public-report', $postDataAry); 

    $patient->printPublicReport($patientId, $appId, $testIds);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Tyler2P ok thanks I'll take care of this from now on